# Subversion (and TortoiseSVN): Is it possible to create a tag directly from an existing tag?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, tags

In my subversion repository, I have the standard `/trunk`, `/branches` and `/tags` folders and a tag, say `/tags/tag1`.

Is it possible to checkout `/tags/tag1`, make some local changes, and then commit directly *as another tag*, say `/tags/tag2`? Can I do this without touching the trunk or any branches?

Also, if this is generally possible using subversion, can it be done with TortoiseSVN?

**Edit:**

If this can be done using TortoiseSVN, I assume it can be done from the command line. What commands would I need to use?

Comment: It appears that the answer to my edit is given at http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.tags.mkcomplex

Comment: For future readers: In svn there's no difference when creating branches or tags. And as "folders" branches, tags, trunk are all equivalent. So all operations from trunk to branches will work from tag to anther tag, branch. Thats why you better take a moment when starting a svn project on how to build your devel tree (trunk, branches, tags being common practice, but not always the best way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this: checkout the tag, then fro the working copy choose Branch/Tag and select "Working copy" in the "Create copy in the repository from:" section, and in the "To URL:" field enter the url of the new tag.

But why you want to do this? Usually, tags are "read-only" snapshots of the state of the code base, and should not be modified.

Comment: Why? I want to make a small change to the code under an existing tag, and then be able to refer to my changed code using a (new) tag. For a single small alteration, I feel that creating a branch from the tag, making the changes and then tagging the branch is overly complex.

Comment: BTW, I agree that tags should not be modified - that's why I want to commit my change as a new tag, rather than commiting again under tags/tag1.

Comment: Usually, you tag the codebase from a branch or from the trunk, so, to make the small change, you modify the working copy of the trunk or the branch and create the tag from there. But of course there is not a "right way" to do the things, so your choice is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: It seems to me that there are two scenarios in which modifying "the working copy of the trunk or the branch" will not work. Firstly, where the trunk or branch has moved on since the tag was made - we don't want the changes to the trunk/branch to be in our new tag. Secondly, the reverse: what if we don't want the changes to our new tag to be on the trunk/branch? In these cases, as far as I can see the only alternative to my proposed method is to create a new branch from the tag.

Comment: There are of course lots of possible scenarios in which your observations are valid.  
If you haven't already done, I would like to suggest you this chapter of the SVN Book which shows two common and very useful strategies to use branches and tags: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.html I hope this could be useful in some way :)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this from TortoiseSVN.
Go to the location of the tag that you locally modified in Windows explorer. Choose 'Branch/ Tag' from the TortoiseSVN context menu.
Now select the TO url to something like 'svn://server/project/tag2'.
Next, for 'Create copy in the repository from', choose the option 'Working Copy'

Answer (score 0):

You can create a branch from `/tags/tag1` to `/tags/tag2`. You can do this without touching the trunk or any existing branches.

We call this hotfix branching, because `/trunk` has moved on, but there's something in `/tags/release-1.0` that needs to be fixed. So we'll branch from `/tags/release-1.0` to `/tags/release-1.0.1`. We'll make the fix and commit to that tag.

Answer (score 0):

Subversion basically treats everything like a directory structure - a tag is simply another folder in the structure that happens to be within a 'tags' directory.

Thus, technically you could check out the `tags` directory, copy one tag folder to a new folder, `svn add` that new folder, and commit it - which would essentially create a new tag based off of the old files. However, you wouldn't get the link between the old tag and the new one (which sort of makes sense - tags aren't supposed to be linked to anything, they're just supposed to be snapshots).

A better scenario if you want good progression of revisions would be to copy the old tag into a branch; make the changes, commit the branch, and then copy the branch back to a new tag. This would preserve the history of the changes much more accurately.

Answer (score 0):

Well You can create a Tag from a Tag, but as mentioned Tags are "read-only" snapshots so better 1st create a Trunc from that earlier Tag say Tag 1 by " Update to Revision" and give particular rev no of Tag1 and then make the changes to Trunc and without svn update/commit of trunc simply Branch a Tag from  trunc and choose working copy and make new tag .Don't forget to switch Trunc at the end of this practice in order to have continuity with svn tags.